# How to click on an element by partial_link?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

this is ths html code :

```
<a href="https://www.decathlon.ca/fr/12547-cyclisme" xpath="1">                                                        Cyclisme
                                                                                                        </a>
```

And im trying to click on this element by this code but not working (Timeout) :

```
    def click_cycling_menu(self):
    cycling_menu_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50)
    cycling_menu_id.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "12547"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use XPath contains functionality?

Feed this into find by xpath:

```
//a[contains(@href,"12547")]
```

Comment: `    def click_cycling_menu(self):
        cycling_menu_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50)
        cycling_menu_id.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href,"12547")]'))).click()`

Comment: not working for me can you click on Allsports/CYCLING in this website https://www.decathlon.ca/en/

Comment: The challenge with explicit waits is it can disguise the problem behind the timeout. When i look at the decathlon site 4 objects match //a[contains(@href,"12547")]  - open devtools, press ctrl+f and paste in the xpath. That will show you where all four are... From that - if you can tell me which one you want to click we can build you a unique xpath

Comment: <a href="https://www.decathlon.ca/en/12547-cycling" style="" xpath="1"></a>

Comment: yes just want to click on cyclism menu under All sport menu

Comment: 3 links match that href, and there's a 4th with a # at the end.  I can't see any object anyhere with a xpath=1 on it.   - none of the 4 objects with the href close without text. 1 has "cylcing" and 2 have "see all cycling"

Comment: Try a new xpath - this is that top cycling under the all sports as requested:  `//li[contains(@class,'cycling')]/div[@class="title"]//a[contains(@href,"/12547")]`

Comment: Happy to help :-)   - you can probably make that xpath shorter - but see where you get to if you have the time

Comment: what is the shorter one

Comment: less needed on the div:  `//li[contains(@class,'cycling')]/div/a[contains(@href,"/12547")]`  - there's only one div beneath the list item and that still identifies same object in my devtools

Comment: Thanks a lot RichEdwards